# Best way to handle Many-to-Many relationships in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

I am looking for the best way to handle a database of many-to-many relationships in PHP and MySQL.

Right now I have 2 tables:

Users (id, user_name, first_name, last_name)
Connections (id_1, id_2)

In the `User` table `id` is auto incremented on add and `user_name` is unique, but can be changed. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the `user_name` and its ability to be changed, but I must account for it.

The `Connections` table is obviously, user1 and user2's id.

The connection table needs to account for these possible relations:

```
user1 --> user2 (user 1 friends with user 2 but not user2 friends with user1) 
user2 --> user1 (user 2 friends with user 1 but not user1 friends with user2) 
user1 <--> user2 (user 1 and user 2 mutually friends) 
user1 <-!-> user2 (user 1 and user 2 not friends)
```

That part is not the problem, The problem I am having with is keeping these relations unique when and if they change in batches.

Possible solution 1: delete all of user 1's relations and readd them with the updated list. I think this might be too slow for my needs.

Solution 2? Anyone else encounter this problem? How should I best handle this?

update: distinguishing relationships:

i handle relationships like this:

```
user1, user2
user1, user3
user2, user1
```

in that example the following is true:
user1 follows user2 and user3
user2 only follows user1 but doesn't follow user3
user3 doesn't follow either user1 or user2

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with your problem, but if the only thing in your Connections table is two user ids, how do you distinguish the different types of relationships?

Comment: @ender, i updated the question with an answer to your question.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities

Comment: @simplemotives, i am using associative entities to create the many-to-many relations, which is why i have a `users` table and a `connections` table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a compound primary key on Connections, using both columns (id_1, id_2) if you're having problems with uniqueness.

Comment: If you don't have a primary key on the Connections table, you should add one. You're probably familiar with selecting a single column as the primary key index, knowing that it must be unique. However, you can use more than one column for an index. Even though there could be duplicate id_1 values, there should never be any duplicate rows for the Connections table (where both id_1 and id_2 are the same), so name both columns id_1, and id_2 in your primary key index. Then, the database won't allow you to have duplicates.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Connections DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id_1, id_2);`