# An effective way to handle one-to-many data updates

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables in my database: `articles`, `tags` and `articles_to_tags`. The latter stores the one-to-many relations. Now, how do I manage those tags when an articles gets updated?

Essentially, I just need to check if there are any new tags that should be added, as well as if there are any tags that should be removed. I guess deleting all corresponding tags and re-adding the needed ones would not be the most effective way?

Here's a suggested similar question, but I didn't get the answer there: [Best way to handle Many-to-Many relationships in PHP MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723962/best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-php-mysql)

Thanks

Comment: Okay so I've just realised that I've seen a much more elegant solution to this which doesn't do the `DELETE`-ing. Seen it in some CMS or a Framework. This is a reminder for myself to find it and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your var/columns and input form something like:

```
$tag_ids    = $_POST['tags']; // all article tags
$article_id = (int)$_POST['article_id'];
```

and doing a necessary check user input, we can delete old tag deleted:

```
// delete unused tag_id for article
$db->query('DELETE FROM articles_to_tags 
            WHERE tag_id NOT IN ('.$db->quote($tag_ids).') 
            AND article_id = ?',Array($article_id));
```

assuming `article_id` and `tag_id` as unique key with an  `insert ignore` statement I can add new tags (and only new tags):

```
// insert new tag and ignore old
$qry = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO articles_to_tags (article_id,tag_id)';
$qry_values = Array();
foreach($tag_ids as $tag_id) {
    qry_values[] = "VALUES ($article_id,$tag_id)";
}
$qry .= implode(", ",$qry_values);
$db->query($qry);
```

Finally with a cron script, I can delete old tags:

```
$db->query('DELETE FROM tags 
            WHERE tag_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT tag_id FROM articles_to_tags)');
```

or you can do it for each article update. I think that’s no so heavy.

Comment: I like the idea. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you show the article, you have all the tags, store them on a array. The user will edit the tags and will submit, these submitted tags must be inside a array so you can compare both, the one that came from database and the one from the form with:

- [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
- [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [sort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Some possible samples:

```
// using sort
sort($array_from_db);
sort($array_from_form);

if($array_from_db == $array_from_from){...}


// using array_diff
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
if(!count($diff)){
  # is the same
}
```